# SQL match strings by percentage

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a SQL table with 2 columns- ID , Value
for example

```
ID   VALUE
1    008_ADL_S81_PCIE_L2_B2B_Cycling_Failure_Phystatus_PP 
2    008_ADL_S81_ABC
3    008_ADL_DEF 
4    008_ADL_XYZ
```

I need to build a query that searches if my string is found in the Value column in my table or it matches by at least 70% if i break / split my string by "underscore" into words
For example, below string matches to my table ID=1 because 90% of the "words" (after splitting by "underscore") are the same, which is above 70%

```
008_ADL_A0_S81_PCIE_L2_B2B_Cycling_Failure_Phystatus_PP
```

How can i do it?

Comment: (1) Define what "70%" match means.  (2) Provide a database tag.  (3) SQL is not usually the best tool for this type of processing.

Comment: 1. 70% match means if i split my string to search by "underscore" into words, and split the Table Value column by "underscore" into words, 70% of the strings are the same

Comment: My DB is SQL ...What other options do i have?

Comment: SQL is just a language. Your database could be SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, to name a few. Each database has a slightly different implementation of Structured Query Language (SQL).

Comment: @MichaelGroiser SQL is just the language not a db , what db engine are you using? I'm guessing since you are in .Net world it is Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Yes . Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: When you say "build a query" do you mean a LINQ query or a SQL query? If a LINQ query, are you using LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x? How large is your table - could you read the entire table into memory and process on the client?

Comment: @MichaelGroiser, first of all try to write SQL and then find a way to express it via LINQ. If it is not possible by the SQL - you have to do client-side processing.

Comment: I can use Linq to SQL/EF . But don't know how to write what i need

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is small enough that loading it locally on the client is not a problem, and assuming you are using LINQ to database and want a LINQ query, you can use:

```
var target = "008_ADL_A0_S81_PCIE_L2_B2B_Cycling_Failure_Phystatus_PP";
var targetHS = target.Split('_', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToHashSet();

var matchingIDs = db.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(s => new { s.ID, words = s.VALUE.Split('_', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) })
                    .Where(s => s.words.Count(w => targetHS.Contains(w)) / s.words.Length >= 0.70)
                    .Select(s => s.ID)
                    .ToList();
```

Alternatively, if the table is large, you could filter the table to rows that contain at least one match, then process the percentages on the client.

Using some extension methods based on [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to build query predicates:

```
public static class LinqKitExt {
    // string fieldExpr(T row) - function returning multiple value string field to test
    // delimiter - string separator between values in test field
    // value - string value to find in values of test field
    // r => fieldExpr(r).Split(delimiter).Contains(value)
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> SplitContains<T>(this Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter, string value) {
        var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r) == value);
        pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).StartsWith(value + delimiter));
        pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).EndsWith(delimiter + value));
        pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).Contains(delimiter + value + delimiter));

        return pred;
    }

    // values - string values, one of which to find in values of test field
    // string fieldExpr(T row) - function returning multiple value string field to test
    // delimiter - string separator between values in test field
    // r => values.Any(value => fieldExpr(r).Split(delimiter).Contains(value))
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AnySplitContains<T>(this IEnumerable<string> values, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter) {
        var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
        foreach (var value in values)
            pred = pred.Or(fieldExpr.SplitContains(delimiter, value));

        return pred;
    }

    // values - string values, one of which to find in values of test field
    // string fieldExpr(T row) - function returning multiple value string field to test
    // delimiter - string separator between values in test field
    // dbq.Where(r => values.Any(value => fieldExpr(r).Split(delimiter).Contains(value)))
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAnySplitContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, IEnumerable<string> values, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter) =>
        dbq.AsExpandable().Where(values.AnySplitContains(fieldExpr, delimiter));
}
```

You can filter the rows first, then pull the possible matches to the client and compute the percentages:

```
var matchingIDs = db.WhereAnySplitContains(targetHS, r => r.VALUE, "_")
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(s => new { s.ID, words = s.VALUE.Split('_', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) })
                    .Where(s => s.words.Count(w => targetHS.Contains(w)) / s.words.Length >= 0.70)
                    .Select(s => s.ID)
                    .ToList();
```